# Should I run checks outside or inside my swap! function?

Tags: clojure

When I'm going to `swap!` the value of an atom conditionally, should the condition wrap the `swap!` or should it be part of the function `swap!` calls?

```
(import '(java.time Instant))

(def not-nil? (comp not nil?))

(defonce users (atom {
  "example user 1" {:ts (Instant/now)}
  "example user 2" {:ts (Instant/now)}
}))

(defn update-ts [id]
  (if (not-nil? (get @users id))
    (swap! users assoc-in [id :ts] (Instant/now))))
```

In the above example, I'm doing the existence check for the user before doing the `swap!`.  But couldn't the user be deleted from `users` after the check but before the `swap!`?  So, then, is it safer to put the check inside the function run by `swap!`?

```
(defn update-ts [id]
  (swap! users (fn [users]
                   (if (not-nil? (get users id))
                       (assoc-in users [id :ts] (Instant/now))
                       users))))
```

Comment: I think the condition should wrap the swap!, also it's going to be easy when debugging.

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇetin That was my natural instinct as seen in my original code.  But I don't want the atom's state to change between the check and this particular `swap!`.

Comment: You might consider configuring your atom with a validator function, if you don't think putting the validation inside the function passed to `swap!` is natural.

Comment: While occasionally a validator can be useful, I don't see how a validator would help here. The question is not about what final states of the atom are valid, but what state transitions are valid for a particular call to `swap!`. Specifically, it is invalid to transition from a non-nil timestamp to any other timestamp value. There's really nowhere to put this check but in the `swap!` itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But couldn't the user be deleted from users after the check but before the `swap!`? So, then, is it safer to put the check inside the function run by `swap!`?

Yes, exactly right. You should never make a decision about how to mutate an atom from anywhere but inside of a `swap!` on that atom. Since `swap!` is the only operation guaranteed to be atomic, every time you do otherwise (ie, make a decision about an atom from outside of a `swap!` on it), you introduce a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

> But couldn't the user be deleted from users after the check but
>   before the swap!? So, then, is it safer to put the check inside the
>   function run by swap!?

As amalloy said, if you need it to be bulletproot you must put the `not-null?` check inside the swap function.

However, please keep in mind that you & your team are writing the rest of the program. Thus, you have a lot of outside information that may simplify your decision:

- If you only ever have one thread (like most programs), you never need to worry about a race condition.
- If you have 2 or more threads, maybe you never remove entries from the map (it only accumulates `:ts` values). Then you also don't need to worry about a conflict.
- If your function is more complicated than the simple example above, you may wish to use a `(dosync ...)` form to wrap multiple steps instead of shoehorning everything in to a single `swap` function.

In the third case, replace the `atom` with a `ref`. An example is:

```
(defonce users (ref {...} )) ; ***** must us a ref here *****
(dosync
  (if (not-nil? (get @users id))
    <lots of other stuff...>
    (alter users assoc-in [id :ts] (Instant/now)))))
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty good argument for a ref instead of an atom.  I have found this answer helpful for explaining the differences.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136699/457586